# azure-spring-boot-starter-keyvault-secrets doesn't work at all

Tags: spring-boot, azure, azure-keyvault

I've integrated azure-spring-boot-starter-keyvault-secrets into two spring-boot services. One simple test-service to play around with it, and one production service. With the test-service it works fine. With the production service, it looks like it doesn't work at all. E.g. I can set an erroneous AKV uri on purpose and it does not create any errors. I'm stuck here, because I have no idea how to figure out, why it is not working. Is there a way to enable debug messages or anything to see whats happening? I'm using spring-boot 2.3.7.RELEASE and azure-spring-boot-starter-keyvault-secrets 3.2.0.

Greets
Harry

Answer (score 0):

@Harry Developer
I'm the developer of azure-spring-boot-starter-keyvault-secrets.

Now there is no such kind of messages. I created a issue to add this feature: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/27167

Answer (score 0):

For this specific question, I've found the reason: I did set the azure.keyvault.* stuff in helm values during deployment, resulting in a configmap. Obviously, this didn't work. I had to set it in src/main/resources/application.yaml using placeholders like ${keyvaulturl}. Setting the placeholders during helm deloyment works in production.